# Does mongodb closes connection automatically?

Tags: mongodb, connection, pymongo

Let me elaborate what all things I have tried:

1. Used `pymongo` module in `python` for remote connection with `mongodb`.
2. Set a breakpoint just after when the connection is established with the database.
   Can see the established connecction with database through following command:
     `sudo lsof | grep mongod | grep TCP`    (tried on ubuntu)
3. But when I exit the code execution directly using `sys.exit()` or when the script gets completely executed the connection is closed automatically.

Does `mongodb` closes the connection automatically ?
I have gone through the `mongodb` documentation but couldn't find any pointers regarding the same.

Please let me know if you have information regarding the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My mongodatabase and the script are on the same local machine.

Comment: sys.exit() raises an exception, I would be surprised if the pymongo driver doesn't clean up when this is raised.

Comment: the operating system does when the process exits

Comment: Python close connections or sockets after ending script, I'm use python script with pymongo in production and he ends connections after close script, but PHP don't close connections automatically, is necesary closed manually. Because same thing happens with MySQL .

Answer (score 2):

Sockets are system resources and if left open are cleaned up by the OS on process termination. Ideally applications (or frameworks/drivers like pymongo in this case) should cleanly shutdown socket before termination, if they don't OS takes care of it without guaranteeing any specific data flow correctness.